# all lambda functions reach the limit at the same time from same API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have 4 lambda functions. I send requests from those 4 functions (with different token) to the same API (also AWS API Gateway). That API have rate limit and when one function reach the rate limit then all of 4 functions also reach the rate limit. I thought 4 functions have the same IP but when I return the public IP from them when they send requests, they have different IP?

Comment: There's no reason to think that HTTP API requests from multiple Lambda function invocations will come from the same IP address unless you attached those Lambda functions to the same VPC and routed their requests via the same NAT.